# after doing left join i am getting duplicate entries. Need to know how to remove duplicate entries

Tags: qlikview

```
LOAD EmployeeID,      
    SickLeaveHours,      
    (8760-SickLeaveHours-VacationHours)as QualityTimeHours,      
    (8760-SickLeaveHours-VacationHours)/24 as QualityDays,       
    ((8760-SickLeaveHours-VacationHours)/24)/30 as QualityMonths,       
    VacationHours;       

SQL SELECT EmployeeID,      
    SickLeaveHours,      
    VacationHours       
FROM Database;      

Join       
LOAD * INLINE [       
    F1, F2        
    ShiftID, Shift      
    1, DAY      
    2, EVENING     
    3, NIGHT      
];      

left join(fact)                 
b:     
LOAD 
    AddressID,
    EmployeeID;      
SQL SELECT 
    AddressID,
    EmployeeID      
FROM Database;      

left join(fact)     
c:     
LOAD 
   DepartmentID,
   EmployeeID;      
SQL SELECT 
   DepartmentID,
   EmployeeID     
FROM Database;           

left join(fact)        
LOAD ShiftID;       
SQL SELECT ShiftID       
FROM  Database;       

left Join (fact)       
d:       
LOAD EmployeeID,      
     Rate;       
SQL SELECT 
    EmployeeID,       
    Rate       
FROM Database ;        

empDetails:          
LOAD BirthDate,         
    EmployeeID,              
    Gender,             
    Title;       
SQL SELECT BirthDate,       
    EmployeeID,        
    Gender,        
    Title         
FROM  Database ;

Department:               
LOAD DepartmentID,         
    GroupName,            
    Name;      
SQL SELECT 
    DepartmentID,              
    GroupName,         
    Name              
FROM  Database;               

Address:           
LOAD AddressID,           
    ModifiedDate,        
    rowguid;           
SQL SELECT 
    AddressID,          
    ModifiedDate,        
    rowguid            
FROM  Database;            

shift:         
LOAD EndTime,       
    Name as name,       
    ShiftID,        
    StartTime;      
SQL SELECT 
    EndTime,         
    Name,         
    ShiftID,         
    StartTime         
FROM  Database;
```

Expected table with no duplicate entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting duplicates because almost all tables are joined to the `fact` table and some of these tables dont have common keys which leads to cross join. For example:

```
left join(fact)        
LOAD ShiftID;       
SQL SELECT ShiftID       
FROM  Database;
```

The script above loads only one field `ShiftID` which do not exists in the `fact` table and the join will basically perform cross join (`all-to-all`)

Qlik joins tables on common field names. If you need to join two tables then these tables should have at least one common field. In your example: `fact` and `EmpAddress` tables will be joined/linked on `EmployeeID` field.

Another point: dont try and always join tables into one. Sometimes is better to just link them. Otherwise you can get wrong/duplicated answers.

For example: `fact` table can have multiple rows per `EmployeeID` and if you join (not link) `EmpDetails` table to `fact` and then count the `Gender` field you will get wrong/duplicated answer. In `one to many` case just link the tables (both tables should have common field(s) but they are not joined. Qlik will automatically link them)

The script below is a version of yours without the "hard" joins to `fact` (dont think you need these joins)

And also - the `shifts` data is not going to be linked to anything since it doesent have any common field with the employee tables

```
fact:
LOAD 
    EmployeeID,      
    SickLeaveHours,      
    (8760-SickLeaveHours-VacationHours)as QualityTimeHours,      
    (8760-SickLeaveHours-VacationHours)/24 as QualityDays,       
    ((8760-SickLeaveHours-VacationHours)/24)/30 as QualityMonths,       
    VacationHours;       
SQL SELECT EmployeeID,      
    SickLeaveHours,      
    VacationHours       
FROM Database;      

EmpAddress:     
LOAD 
    EmployeeID,
    AddressID;      
SQL SELECT 
    AddressID,
    EmployeeID      
FROM Database; 

EmpDepartment:     
LOAD 
   EmployeeID,
   DepartmentID;      
SQL SELECT 
   DepartmentID,
   EmployeeID     
FROM Database;           

EmpRate:       
LOAD EmployeeID,      
     Rate;       
SQL SELECT 
    EmployeeID,       
    Rate       
FROM Database;        

EmpDetails:          
LOAD
    EmployeeID,
    BirthDate,              
    Gender,             
    Title;       
SQL SELECT BirthDate,       
    EmployeeID,        
    Gender,        
    Title         
FROM  Database ;

Department:               
LOAD 
    DepartmentID,         
    GroupName,            
    Name             as DeprtmentName;      
SQL SELECT 
    DepartmentID,              
    GroupName,         
    Name              
FROM  Database;               

Address:           
LOAD AddressID,    
    ModifiedDate     as Address_ModifiedDate,        
    rowguid;           
SQL SELECT 
    AddressID,          
    ModifiedDate,        
    rowguid            
FROM  Database;            


// This part of the script will be isolated from the rest
// because there is no key to join on
shift:         
LOAD
    Name as ShiftName,       
    ShiftID,
    EndTime,
    StartTime;      
SQL SELECT 
    EndTime,         
    Name,         
    ShiftID,         
    StartTime         
FROM  Database;  

Join       
LOAD * INLINE [       
    ShiftID, Shift      
    1, DAY      
    2, EVENING     
    3, NIGHT      
];    

// Is this table needed at all?
LOAD ShiftID;       
SQL SELECT ShiftID       
FROM  Database;
```

Comment: well, the above code creates EmployeeID as PK for all dimensions. I would like to assign Pk for  AddressID,  DepartmentID,Rate etc without affecting the database. Or else we need to create a table in qlikview assigning PK and FK without disturbing Actual datawarehouse.

Comment: A star schema is what i am expecting. Assigning Pk in dimensions and linking to fact table as FK

Comment: what do you mean with "without affecting the database"? Qlik is not writing to the dabase

Comment: Got it, but can you help me in figuring to get a star schema, instead of making employeedid as pk for all. Could we connect online